# Synching Data on App Installation

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am successfully using JobScheduler to sync online data into my app at regular intervals.

My question is if it is possible to run the JobScheduler as soon as the app is installed rather than having to wait until the main activity is created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, sorry. First, nothing runs as soon as the app is installed. Second, you do not control when `JobScheduler` runs its jobs.